# optimizing sql UNION queries

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, merge, union

I have three "main" tables (let's call them tb1_1, tb2_1 and tb3_1) containing input (info & indexes) data and other tables containing the value of theses indexes.
Then, I have a bunch of views to process the data in the tables and the final output view is the one linked to excel for further processing.
When I request an update of the data (views), it takes maximum 10 seconds to get back the hand. So far so good.

Now, here comes the "problem": I have been asked to add more "main" data from a different source. I am not a sql expert, so this is what I did so far:

I created three new "main" tables: tb1_2, tb2_2 and tb3_2. They are next to my other "main" tables

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tb1_2;
CREATE TABLE tb1_2 (
    id bigint(20),
    data1 bigint(20),
    data2 date,
    data3 varchar(64),
    ...
);
```

As the index of the new tables are overlaping with the old ones, I have created a view, with the UNION of these new tables and the content of the old tables where the index is more than 10000. So I have now: view1, view2, view3 (which are then the "merge" of two tables):

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS view1;
CREATE VIEW view1 AS
SELECT  id, data1, data2, ... FROM tb1_2
UNION ALL
SELECT  id, data1, data2, ... FROM tb1_1
WHERE id >= 10000;
```

Then, in my queries to generate the views that process the data, I replaced all tb1_1 by view1, tb1_2 by view2 and tb1_3 by view3

It all works fine, I get in my final view the "new" data added to the "old" data.
However, it takes 5 minutes to get the data back, instead of the 10 seconds previously.

Any idea how I can improve the cycle time/performance ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Do you have all the indexes in the new table that was in the old table? Indexes are crucial for speed in SQL.

Comment: *As the index of the new tables are overlaping with the old ones* I don't follow. Is that "Index" a master table? If so we might go around in circles while trying to describe the importance of indexes on your tables.  consider providing FULL DDL for each table (includes constratint/index information. Also: are the 3 new tables in the same database or in some remote (linked) database?

Comment: sorry, not a sql expert. By "index" I meant the first 'id' column. Now, in the original first table, this 'id' is also marked as "PK AI' in Workbench (from 1 till >35000). This is maybe what you call index. In the second table, that I created by script, I have just used numbers (8000 till 9000, given numbers that cannot be changed). I do not know how to 'mark' it as "PK AI" to speed up the process, if this can help.

Comment: If you are providing the numbers, don't make it AI (`AUTO_INCREMENT`).  A PK (`PRIMARY KEY`) is an index.

Comment: Does the operation run faster when using the `UNION` spelled out than when using the `VIEW` containing that `UNION`?  If so, then you have hit one of many situations where `VIEW` is syntactic sugar but not good at performing.

Comment: Thank you for your help so far. I could search for `INDEX` and `PRIMARY KEY`.

Comment: I could also then find the source code that created the old tables, and applied the same to my new tables `INDEX datan, INDEX datan+1, PRIMARY KEY(id)`. I do not see an improvement in performance.

Comment: Note that my new tables do not have all the columns of the old tables. I just created the columns needed in the views I generate from these tables. The `UNION` view I create (view1) only selects required columns  (so a selection from tb1_1 [old table] and all colunms from tb2_1 [my new table]) used to generate other views. And my new tables also have a limited number of raws, in sorted order, but not with all numbers (could be 8001, 8002, 8012, 8025,...). I do not know if both can be a root cause for performance issue. @Rick can you please explain `UNION` spelled out versus `VIEW`

Comment: What do you mean by "INDEX datan+1"?  Looks like a syntax error.

Comment: Tables do not have an any order.  To see the rows in a particular order, you must use `ORDER BY...`.

Comment: When you `SELECT` from a `VIEW`, the code is actually performing the `SELECT` defined inside the `VIEW` definition.  That is, there is not a 'materialized' copy; it's all smoke and mirrors.